# UAC should always let me input user name

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, uac, user

I am using Windows 10 (1703) and I see two different kinds of UAC dialogs (with respect to behaviour):

(1) User field is editable immediately

[image: (1) UAC - User field is editable]

(2) At least 2 clicks required before editing of user field is possible

(2a)

[image: (2a) UAC - User field is not editable]

(2b)

[image: (2b) UAC - User field is not editable]

(1) Is shown for verified publishers. (2) Is shown either when I perform run as Administrator to start a batch script and the like or for unverified publishers.

It is very annoying to select run as Administrator and get presented the UAC dialog with a non admin user and, to make it totally cumbersome, not being able to override the non admin user with an admin user - at least not without the need of two preceding mouse clicks.

**Question:** Is there a possibility to always show the UAC with an immediately editable user field?

Comment: The difference between the two UAC is that the first one was not launched with the runas while the second one, based on the screenshot was run as the user`SCHAULER/schema`.  Provide more information how you are getting each case.  I was unable to reproduce this behavior personally on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: @Ramhound I will get both kinds of dialogs by run as depending on the executable and I will get both kinds of dialogs by just double clicking as well. Maybe this can have somthing to do with my companies domain settings?

Comment: Due to the fact, your screenshots are not in English, I can only go by what I believe is the case, is that the 2b is asking for the password for the user schema on the domain SCHAUER.  We expect questions here at SU to be in English, likewise, screenshots should either also be in English or a translation should be provided.

Comment: @Ramhound: Fair enough. I added translations for clarification.